# Plot "extended" predicted survival on top of KM ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, survival

I would like to have those two plots gathered on one single plot. This would allow me to check how survival evolve on the long run while visually assessing the goodness of fit of the distribution.

Can you help me?

[image: Current KM with flexsurvreg]

```r
library(survminer)
require(flexsurv)
data(bc)

su_obj <- Surv(bc$rectime, bc$censrec)

fit_0 <- do.call(flexsurvreg, list(formula =su_obj~group, data = bc, dist = "exponential"))

ggsurvplot(fit_0)
```

[image: Extended predicted survival based on flexsurvreg]

```r
time_0 = 5000

survival_ext = summary(fit_0, type = "survival",t=1:time_0)

survival_ext = as.data.frame(survival_ext)

survival_ext = survival_ext[,grep(".est", names(survival_ext))]

survival_ext = cbind(1:time_0, survival_ext)

names(survival_ext)[1]="time"

survival_ext = reshape2::melt(survival_ext,id="time") 

ggplot(survival_ext,aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Time",
       y="Survival probability",
       color="")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine there are a number of different thoughts about this, but here is one simple approach if it helps.

```
fit_0_obj <- ggsurvplot(fit_0)

ggplot(survival_ext,aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Time",
       y="Survival probability",
       color="") +
  geom_step(data = fit_0_obj$data.survplot, aes(x=time, y=surv, color=group))
```

**Edit (9/20/21)**: With a [bug](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/408#issuecomment-557171782) in the `survminer` package, the "group" in the bc data needs to be character and not a factor. Until fixed, you can do the following to reproduce the plot:

```
bc$group <- as.character(bc$group)
```

[image: survival curve]

Comment: Waw exactly what I was looking for Txs

Comment: I tried using the code (after searching for a package with a bc data object that has the needed columns) and get an error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found"

Comment: This works if you change group to character instead of factor in the bc data...I found a bug in the survminer package with `ggflexsurvplot` from the commit in July 2019 (the code has `as.facet` instead of `as.factor` when checking if factor or character...). I will follow up on github...